# Blackberry dev - Question about jre 1.5

Tags: blackberry, arraylist, java

I THINK I know the answer to this, but can't find any plain English to confirm it.

I am currently porting an Android app to blackberry. I've gotten over most problems, but ArrayLists are the one I'm stuck on, since they were only introduced in 1.5 .

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to develop for newer blackberry devices, while having java compliance set to 1.5?

I'm thinking that J2ME is the deciding factor with blackberry. So if that only supports 1.3, then EVERY app made for blackberry must be written in eclipse with a compliance level of 1.3 set, and any newer blackberrys would be the same, and therefore ArrayLists are impossible.

Can someone confirm this for me?

Thanks.

PS Would it be possible to create my own ArrayList class, with the angle brackets `< >` as well?

Comment: The angle brackets (generics) weren't introduced until 1.5. I'm not sure which versions can be used with newer blackberry devices, but if they don't support 1.5, you won't be able to use generics even in a custom class.

Comment: Also, ArrayList were introduced since Java 1.2. Generics were introduced in JDK 5.

Comment: I use 1.3 Java compliance in Eclipse. As Michael B. said just use `Vector` instead of `List`. Generics are not supported in BB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use Java 1.4 compliance for BlackBerry because they use J2ME.

Use Vector for your dynamic list. You can't use Generics<>.